# Python3 json output values to file line by line only if other fields are greater than value

Tags: json, python-3.x, urllib

I have retrieved remote json using urllib.request in python3 and would like to to dump, line by line, the value of the IP addresses only (ie. ip:127.0.0.1 would be 127.0.0.1, next line is next IP) if it matches certain criteria. Other key values include a score (one integer value per category) and category (one or more string values possible).

I want to check if the score is higher than, say 10, AND the category number equals a list of one OR more values. If it fits the params, I just need those IP addresses added line by line to a text file.

Here is how I retrieve the json:

```
ip_fetch = urllib.request.urlopen('https://testonly.com/ip.json').read().decode('utf8')
```

I have the json module loaded, but don't know where to go from here.

Example of json data I'm working with, more than one category:

```
   "127.0.0.1" : {
      "Test" : "10",
      "Prod" : "20"
   },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a simple example that should show you how to iterate trough json objects and how to write to a file:

```
import json
j = json.loads(test)

threshold = 10
validCategories = ["Test"]

f=open("test.txt",'w')
for ip, categories in j.items():
    addToList = False
    for category, rank in categories.items():
        if category in validCategories and int(rank) >= threshold:
            addToList = True
    if addToList:
        f.write("{}\n".format(ip))
f.close()
```

I hope that helps you to get started. For testing I used the following json-string:

```
test = """
{
    "127.0.0.1" : {
          "Test" : "10",
          "Prod" : "20"
    },

    "127.0.0.2" : {
          "Test" : "5",
          "Prod" : "20"
    },

    "127.0.0.3" : {
          "Test" : "5",
          "Prod" : "5",
          "Test2": "20"
    }
}
"""
```